# Java 8 regex: a capturing group in a pattern doesn't match, yet the whole pattern does match

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

This is my first question. Nice to e-meet everyone.

I have created the following regex pattern in Java 8 (this is just a simplified example of what I actually have in my code - for the sake of clarity):

```
(?<!a)([0-9])\,([0-9])(?!a)|(?<!b)([0-9]) ([0-9])(?!b)|(?<!c)([0-9])([0-9])(?!c)
```

so in general it consists of three alternatives:
1st one matches two single digits separated with a comma, for example:

```
1,1
2,0
4,5
```

2nd one matches two single digits separated with a space, for example:

```
1 1
2 0
4 5
```

3rd one matches two single digits in a row, for example:

```
11
20
45
```

Each alternative uses lookarounds and their content has to be slightly different for each one of them - that's why I couldn't just put everything together like that:

```
([0-9])[, ]?([0-9])
```

Each of the matched digits is enclosed in a capturing group and now I have a second line to 'call out' these captured numbers like this:

```
(?<!n)($1 $2|$3 $4|$5 $6)(?!n)
```

So at the end I need to match a text that would have the same digits separated with single space and not surrounded by 'n'. So if any of the examples shown above would be matched by the pattern from the 1st line, the 2nd line pattern should match these:

```
1 1
2 0
4 5
11 11
22 00
44 55
```

And not any of these:

```
n1 1
2,0
45
asd asd asd
```

The problem is the following: it returns a match even if I do not have these captured digits in the tested text, **but I do have space** in it... So here I do not get match and that is correct:

```
aaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbb
aasdfasdf
```

but here I get a match on the following things (most apparently because there is a space/spaces):

```
abc abc
q w r t y
as df
```

Does anyone know if this is normal that despite the fact that the characters in capturing groups are not captured by the 1st line, the 'non capturing group' part (so a single space) will be matched and therefore the whole pattern returns match, as if a capturing group could be a zero-length match in the second line if nothing is captured by the first line? Thanks in advance for any comment on this.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with  the simplified regex (besides the fact that it is a regex, and a quite complex one :) ). Maybe there is a typo in the coded regex, so please show it if you want an answer. But better use String.split and maybe Integer.parseInt or something that simple and readable to solve your task. Otherwise, you are going to solve 2 tasks.

Comment: is it possible, that you confuse ["capturing groups"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) ("brackets") with ["lookaraounds"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? ...what  should the `(?<!a)`, `(?<!b)`, `(?<!c)` do/match?

Comment: “I have a second line to 'call out' these captured numbers like this:” I don’t understand this part.  What does “call out” mean?  The code has $1, $2, etc., suggesting it’s a replacement string, but it also has lookbehind and lookahead, which does nothing in a replacement string.

Comment: Are you trying to use backreferences or replacements? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for comments! A few notes to clarify: @VGR This is code for a software checking translations: in the 1st line/field I enter regex pattern that will match in the source (original) text and in the 2nd line/field I enter regex pattern that will match in the target (translation) text. I can use backreferences in one of the lines to 'call out' what has been captured in the other one. That's why I have lookarounds in both lines, they ensure that what's matched in the source text isn't surrounded by 'a', 'b' or 'c' respectively and what's matched in the target text is not surrounded by 'n'.

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin , yes, it's quite complex, the 'real' code looks like this, it's rather okay, I've tried the simiplified example to be just the same (we use our own `\p{sp}` for spaces instead of `\s`): 1st line (source text): `(?<![A-Za-z]|[0-9]\,?)([0-9]{2})\,([0-9]{3})(?!\,[0-9]|[A-Za-z])|(?<![A-Za-z]|[0-9]\p{sp}?)([0-9]{2})\p{sp}([0-9]{3})(?!\p{sp}?[0-9]|[A-Za-z])|(?<![A-Za-z]|[0-9]\.?|\p{L}\-|(?:#|CFR|IEC|ISO|PN|REF)\p{sp}?|(?:[Nn]o\.|number)\p{sp}?)([1-9]{1}[0-9]{1})([0-9]{3})(?![0-9])` and 2nd line (target text): `(?<![0-9]\p{sp}?)($1\p{sp}$2|$3\p{sp}$4|$5\p{sp}$6)(?!\p{sp}?[0-9])`

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your comment! So in general this is a normal behavior that if a backreference fails to match it still 'matches' nothing? That should explain the problem. (Can you comment a little bit more on this? Is it possible to read about it somewhere? I've looked on the most popular sites and found no clue.) If so,I won't use backreferences divided into alternatives. I was aware that the ultimate solution would be to split code and keep everything separately, but I was hoping to avoid it as I have to split four similar entries into 12 separate ones and I have to do it in 70+ files.

Comment: @Kacper I had assumed that was the problem but it turns out I'm incorrect ([doc](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html), [test](https://ideone.com/9NZezy))

Comment: There's a typo in my test (the backslash of the backreference should be escaped) but fixing it doesn't change the outcome

Comment: In my opinion, when a regular expression gets that complex, it’s time to write a parser.  You can still make use of short regular expressions, but there’s nothing wrong with using multiple lines of code to parse.  After all, you can be certain that your large regular expression will be processed by many lines of code internal to the java.util.regex package.  And consider this:  if you have to come back to this code in a year, how long will it take you to fully understand that regex?

Comment: @VGR, you are right that the best solution here is to divide it into multiple lines and I will do it like this.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches whitespace because the resulting pattern for the `1,1` string is `(?<!n)(1 1| | )(?!n)`, and it can match a space that is neither preceded nor followed with a space.

**When a replacement backreference does not match any string** in a `.replaceAll`/`.replaceFirst` **it is assigned an empty string** (it is assigned *null* when using `.find()` / `.matches()`), and thus you still get the blank alternatives in the resulting pattern.

You may leverage this functionality AND the fact that each alternative has exactly two capturing groups by **concatenating replacement backreferences** in the string replacement pattern, getting rid of the alternations altogether:

**SEARCH**: `(?<!a)([0-9]),([0-9])(?!a)|(?<!b)([0-9]) ([0-9])(?!b)|(?<!c)([0-9])([0-9])(?!c)`
**REPLACE**: `(?<!n)($1 $2|$3 $4|$5 $6)(?!n)`

Note how the backreferences are concatenated: all backreferences to odd groups come first, then all backreferences to even groups are placed in a no-alternative pattern.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uy5D8f/2).

Note that **even if the number of groups is different across the alternatives** you may just add "fake" empty groups to each of them, and this approach will still work.